# How to reduce file size of jpeg without losing its quality

Tags: jpeg

I want to reduce the size of jpg's I use on my website. Is there a way to reduce the size of jpg files so that I can reduce the data transfer charges without reducing much of clarity? I am hoping to do this without uploading my files somewhere.

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server?  Also, what OS is it running if you do?

Comment: @jconder How any of this can help in repacking jpgs with a better compression?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I reduce the file size of a JPEG keeping the same image width and height?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/21648)

Comment: @GSerg because if the asker has SSH access with say, linux, then he could install ImageMagick and run a batch command to convert them all to lower quality.

Comment: 2 ways to reduce size 1. Change quality usually 10-20% in quality reduction do not show any visiable effect if you are using hq image or 2. Cropping or changing dimensions. Simple Image is easy to impliment and use https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to shrink JPG files on web is to use [shrinkjpeg.com](http://shrinkjpeg.com). The reason I recommend shrinkjpeg.com is because the site compresses JPG Images without actually uploading the files to their server (Who knew HTML5 magic can do this locally?)

Answer (score 2):

[Nearly] Any application of JPEG is going to distort the image from the original. You can adjust the compression settings to balance compression to image distortion. The amount of compression you can get without visible distortion depends upon the type of image. If you have a cartoon with sharp color transitions, you are going to quickly see distortions with JPEG.

Things you can do to change compression:

1. Change the quantization tables ("Quality Settings" in many encoders)
2. Subsample the Cb and Cr components.
3. Use optimal Huffman tables (has no visible effect the image)